# Cannot add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

Developing in Visual Studio 2013 and suddenly a yellow sign appeared with SharePoint.dll. I removed the dll and tried to add it again. Now i am getting the following error

[image]

I also tried to create new empty SharePoint project and same problem there.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before and eventually know how to fix it.

Comment: Check the .dll path. Does this dll exist in the above path?

Comment: Yes dll is there.

Comment: Have you installed SharePoint foundation or SharePoint server platform?

Comment: @DikeshGandhi SharePoint Server. Also its not new installation. Has been working on the same mashine for long time and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Can you please `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI` open it in your file explorer and check if `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` exists.

Comment: @AsadRefai Yes dll is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that dll was currupt. There was no digital signature and nothing in the details tab.

[image]

After replacing dll from another environment everything works fine now.

Comment: Please mark as an answer.